# Showing that all gomory hu trees of $K_{3,3}$ are stars with 5 edges

Tags: graphs, trees

My lecture notes for gomory-hu trees says that it's easy to see that every GHT of the utility graph $K_{3,3}$ is a star with 5 edges. Is there any easy way to see this without manually computing every gomory-hu tree of the graph? Could I make use of the symmetry of the graph?

Comment: What are the weights of the edges in $K_{3,3}$? I don't think this is true for all possible weights.

Answer (score 0):

**Outline:** 
For generality, we will be looking at $K_{n,n}$ with $n\ge3$ and all edge weights equal to 1.
One can prove that any (s,t)-mincut in $K_{n,n}$ cuts off exactly one vertex.
From that, it follows that the longest path in the GHT has length <=2. The only connected graph with this property is an (2n-1)-star.

---

**Lemma 1:** Any (s,t)-mincut in $K_{n,n}$ with $n\ge3$ cuts off exactly one vertex.

**Proof:**

- The vertices of $K_{n,n}$ can, by definition be partitioned into two subsets such that no edge has both endpoints in the same subset. Call these subsets $L$ and $R$.
- Consider any cut and call the smallest connected component after cutting $C$. $C$ contains $i$ vertices from $L$ and $j$ vertices from $R$, with $1\le i+j\le n$. Now $$w(C)=i(n-j)+j(n-i)=n(i+j)-2ij$$
- A cut that cuts off one vertex has weight $n$.
- A cut that cuts off 2 or more vertices has (by AM-GM) weight
  \begin{align}
  w(C)
  &\ge n(i+j)-\frac{1}{2}(i+j)^2 \\
  &= (i+j)(n-\frac{i+j}{2}) \\
  &\ge 2\cdot \frac{n}{2}=n
  \end{align}
  Where equality holds iff 2=i+j=n, which is impossible for $n\ge3$
- Thus the (s,t)-mincuts in $K_{n,n}$ are the cuts that cut off only $s$ or only $t$.

**Lemma 2:** Every path in the GHT has length $< 3$

**Proof:**
If there was a path $(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)$ with $k\ge4$, then $GHT \setminus (v_2v_3)$ would have two connected components of size $\ge2$ each. Because of the properties of GHTs, a $(v_2v_3)$-mincut in $K_{n,n}$ would have the same connected components, which contradicts Lemma 1.

**Lemma 3:** Any GHT of $K_{n,n}$ is a (2n-1)-star.

**Proof:**
The only connected graph with the preceding property is a star.